# Show precalculated nonadditive hierarchical data in Power BI

Tags: matrix, powerbi, hierarchical-data, interactive, levels

I have hierarchical data where parent values are already calculated figures from the source. I would like to show those data interactively in Power BI with level selection etc. The data can be represented as 'distinct customers', for example:

[image]

What would be the best format of source data and which visual to use?

Ideal solution:

- flexible number of levels
- as little DAX as possible

I already tried hierarchical slicer but I cannot provide values column to it. Matrix demands a function for aggregation which I don't have.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix visual, this give you the same type of structure.
You would add holding company then the company then the account managers into the row section. You then style this visual how ever you like